# Google Maps Clustering

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Hi I am making a map view for my classified ads site and I am having trouble adding a clustering function to the map. I was wondering if anybody could help me and offer some advice as to how I can edit my code to make the clustering work for all the ads on my site because as it is right now it displays all my ads accordingly but it just doesn't cluster them when I add cluster code for some reason, I'm a bit of a newb so I'm obviously inputting the code wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


    var markersInfo = $('.ia-card').map(function() {

            var info = {
                id: $(this).data('map-id'),
                address: $(this).data('map-address'),
                title: $(this).data('map-title'),
                price: $(this).data('map-price'),
                latitude: $(this).data('map-latitude'),
                longitude: $(this).data('map-longitude'),
                html: "<img src=" + $(this).data('map-image') + ">",
                link: $(this).data("map-link"),
        contentHtml:  "<div class='image'>" + "<img src=" + $(this).data('map-image') + ">" + "</div>" + '<b>' + $(this).data('map-title') + '</b><br>' + $(this).data('map-price') + "<br><a href='" + $(this).data("map-link") + "'>More>></a>"
            };

        return info;
    }).get();


        initGoogleMap(markersInfo);




// GMAP ON SEARCH RESULTS PAGE
function initGoogleMap(markersInfo) {

    var mapOptions = {
        // zoom: 2,
        // center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.334430, -7.736673) // center of Ireland
    },
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
    mapElement = document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



    $.each(markersInfo, function(key, val) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: {lat: parseFloat(val.latitude), lng: parseFloat(val.longitude)},
            title: val.title,
            info: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: val.contentHtml
            })

        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            marker.info.open(map, marker);
        });


        loc = new google.maps.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude);
            bounds.extend(loc);
    });


    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.panToBounds(bounds);

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersInfo, {
        zoomOnClick: true,
        gridSize: 40,
        maxZoom: 15,
        imagePath: 'images/m',
        minimumClusterSize: 2
        });

};


});
```

Comment: I do not see anything related to clustering in your code.. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Comment: Yeah I know, I am hoping someone can add clustering code to the above piece of code as that is the code that works in terms of displaying and populating all of my ads on the map. I just need to add a clustering function to them.

Comment: No one will just add code. That is not what we do on SO. But if you show the code that does not work we could help you figure how to solve it. (*other than that, the code I linked show exactly what you are asking*)

Comment: Oh right my bad, as I said I'm new to Stack Overflow so I am not entirely sure how things work... but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the when passing the marker list to the `MarkerClusterer` you need to pass it as an array of actual google markers.

So you need to store the markers (not their info, but the actual markers) in an array and pass that on.

You also should not set the `map` property of each marker as that adds it to the map directly, while you want the `MarkerClusterer` to handle that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var markersInfo = $('.ia-card').map(function() {

    var info = {
      id: $(this).data('map-id'),
      address: $(this).data('map-address'),
      title: $(this).data('map-title'),
      price: $(this).data('map-price'),
      latitude: $(this).data('map-latitude'),
      longitude: $(this).data('map-longitude'),
      html: "<img src=" + $(this).data('map-image') + ">",
      link: $(this).data("map-link"),
      contentHtml: "<div class='image'>" + "<img src=" + $(this).data('map-image') + ">" + "</div>" + '<b>' + $(this).data('map-title') + '</b><br>' + $(this).data('map-price') + "<br><a href='" + $(this).data("map-link") + "'>More>></a>"
    };

    return info;
  }).get();

  initGoogleMap(markersInfo);

  // GMAP ON SEARCH RESULTS PAGE
  function initGoogleMap(markersInfo) {

    var mapOptions = {
        // zoom: 2,
        // center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.334430, -7.736673) // center of Ireland
      },
      bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
      mapElement = document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions),
      markerList = []; // create an array to hold the markers

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    $.each(markersInfo, function(key, val) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        /*map: map,*/ // do not set the map on each marker
        position: {
          lat: parseFloat(val.latitude),
          lng: parseFloat(val.longitude)
        },
        title: val.title,
        info: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: val.contentHtml
        });
      });

      markerList.push(marker); // add the marker to the list

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.info.open(map, marker);
      });

      loc = new google.maps.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude);
      bounds.extend(loc);
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.panToBounds(bounds);

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerList, {
      zoomOnClick: true,
      gridSize: 40,
      maxZoom: 15,
      imagePath: 'images/m',
      minimumClusterSize: 2
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the speedy reply, but unfortunately the map doesn't seem to load anymore with the above code you provided :/

Comment: Ok I tinkered with it and it' loading and the clustering works now but for some reason it' displaying the wrong number of markers, for example I have 3 markers in similar locations but it says 36 inside the marker cluster for some reason....any suggestion as to why this might be happening?

Comment: @RogerAlridge do you have the code somewhere live ? Or can you createa codepen or jsfiddle that shows the problem ?

Comment: The site is locked as it is a client's site and I don't know how I can set up a jsfiddle for that. I can provide screenshots, would that help?

Comment: @RogerAlridge not really :/ We would need to see the problem in action and be able to change things..

Comment: How would I go about creating a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: Go to https://jsfiddle.net/ and create a minimal example that shows the problem. Add the html/css/js (*use hardcoded points for ease of use*), save it and share here the link to the saved fiddle.

Comment: @RogerAlridge can you also do a `console.log( JSON.stringify(markersInfo) );` right after you fill the variable and share the json here.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that lol, the jsfiddle is no good no?

Comment: @RogerAlridge it has no markers as they are created from the html that is missing. That is why i say that in your code (in your own page that has the problem) to run the above command in your script so that it prints (*in the console*) the `markersInfo` array with the data. Then we can add them to the jsfiddle and see the problem.

Comment: So in your code just change `initGoogleMap(markersInfo);` to `console.log( JSON.stringify(markersInfo) ); initGoogleMap(markersInfo);` reload the page and see the console for the info

Comment: Ok I have done that, I am using Google Chrome, do I need to download the console or do I just cop and paste the code in to the fiddle?

Comment: Put the JSON from the console to https://pastebin.com/ or add it to the jsfiddle and update it (*remove sensitive info if there is any, first*)

Comment: @RogerAlridge your JSON (*which means your html, since that is where the json was created from*) has repeating items (the same item multiple times). So each marker appears 18 times. Looks like some issue with how you load the `.ia-card` elements in the page (*are you appending and keeping old ones ?*). So that is where you should be looking for the problem.

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vugqxbn8/2/ The pastebin had the json twice, so it is really 9 times per item. The items in Dublin are 4 and since you have 9 times the same info, you get 4*9=36 markers.

Comment: hmmm that's interesting, well I don't have the ia-card code anywhere else but how it is written above so is there a way to edit that to fix the issue at hand? Thanks for all your help by the way, I really appreciate your patience with me :)

Comment: @RogerAlridge the correct way is to fix the html. But since we do not have that you can filter the info to keep distinct values only. Here is you initial code updated with some code to keep only the distinct marker info. https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vugqxbn8/7/

Comment: You my friend are a LIFESAVER!! Thank you so much for everything!! Seriously can't thank you enough :D